# Working with <p:rowToggler /> with Text as Label instead Symbol of toggler

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, stylesheet

I am using *p:dataTable* with *p:rowToggler*, i want to show toggler in text instead of round circle symbol.How to Label *p:rowToggler*

i am tring this style for showing Text ***Process***   _ but how can i bind with *p:rowToggler*?

```
<style>
.toggler {
content: "Process";
}
</style>
```

and is it right way to implement?
when i click on text or link, would be like rowExpantion
please help me out from this

Answer (score 2):

I am using PF 6.1 and row toggler has `expandLabel` and `collapseLabel` Not sure when these first became available.

```
<p:rowToggler expandLabel="View History" collapseLabel="Hide History"/>
```

css would be

```
.ui-datatable .ui-row-toggler {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```